# Get Multiple results through sqlReader

Tags: c#

I am having problems with sqlreader. it only displays the first result when I need it to display all records in the column.
I have searched thoroughly on this site and every answer doesn't seem to work for me.
Here is my code:

```
str2 = "SELECT CPU FROM Clients";
            connection = new SqlConnection(str);
            connection.Open();
            command = new SqlCommand(str2, connection);
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            try
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    num = 0;
                    string col1Value = reader[0].ToString();
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        enumerator = reader.GetEnumerator();
                        record = (DbDataRecord)enumerator.Current;
                        if (j.Connect(out j))
                        {
                            //string col1Value = reader[0].ToString();//str3 = reader["CPU"].ToString();
                            num += 1;
                            MessageBox.Show(col1Value);
                            if (col1Value == j.GetCPUKey())
                            {
                                this.j.XNotify("Connected! Welcome: " + j.GetCPUKey());
                                MessageBox.Show(col1Value);
                                connection.Close();
                                CheckAuth();
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("You Are Not Authorised!");
                                connection.Close();
                            }
                            if (!j.Connect(out j))
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("Could Not Connect to Default Console");
                                connection.Close();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("" + ex);
                Environment.Exit(0);
                connection.Close();
            }
```

Please Help.

Comment: Why are you closing your connection inside of your loop? Closing the connection ... well it closes the connection = no more data. Also a relational database works by showing columns in a record, not records in a column. Also what is `j`? Also why `reader.HasRows` inside the while loop as if you are in the while loop you are already pointing to the first record so this is always true?

Comment: even without the closing of the connection, it still shows one row. j is from a library i am using, it has nothing to do with the reader.

Comment: See the documentation for SqlReader.Read, it advances the reader to the next available record and returns true, it returns false if there are no records. It means that inside the loop the reader has been advanced

Comment: Also what is this? `j.Connect(out j)` - this seems like bad design, changing the pointer of `j` inside of a call to the `j` instance.

Comment: as I said, The library I'm using wasn't created by me, thats just the way its called. Thanks for your help, ill look at the documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is all you want to do (check if a 'CPU' is authorized or not) then you have a lot of code that you don't really need.
Just ask the database to search for the CPU value you want

```
try
{
    if (j.Connect(out j))
    {       
         string cpuToSearchFor = j.GetCPUKey();
         str2 = "SELECT CPU FROM Clients WHERE CPU = @cpu";
         using(connection = new SqlConnection(str))
         using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(str2, connection);
         {
             connection.Open();
             command.Parameters.Add("@cpu", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = cpuToSearchFor;
             using(reader = command.ExecuteReader())
             {
                 if(reader.HasRows)
                 {
                    MessageBox.Show("Authenticated");
                    j.XNotify("Connected! Welcome: " + cpuToSearchFor);
                    CheckAuth();
                 }   
                 else
                    MessageBox.Show("Unauthorized");
             }
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show("" + ex);
   Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

In this approach there is no need to loop over the records returned by the query because you have no record if the database cannot find the CPU requested. Thus is just a matter to check if the reader has record or not.

Notice also that the using statement allows you to remove all those lines that manage the closing of the connection. The connection is automatically closed on the exit from the using block.